# simultaneously record audio and convert to text

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I have developed an app that records an audio for a particular duration, another one which uses web to convert speech to text.
Is it possible that both the things can be done simultaneously? I mean to record an audio and convert the speech available in that recorded audio file to text?

Comment: I assume you've tried putting them in two separate threads? Although that'll probably fail as you would be trying to access the same audio file concurrently. You probably need to wait to close the audio file, then upload it. One option might be to record the audio in chunks using silence detection, and process it a few words at a time

Comment: I dint implement uploading of the audio file in the speech to text conversion app yet.Is it possible to do so?If yes, can you please help me out with resources??

Comment: I just assumed you were uploading it. However you're doing the speech to text, I think the only way to do it is to save the audio as small chunks, and process each one individually

Comment: is it possible to store the audio and convert to text using the available google API

Answer (score -1):

The way you're doing this might not be very accurate, as there are many different suggestions to the voice input. But you can give it a hit.
By what i understood, you should run audio in background service and start voice detection.
For background service [this](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html) is how you use them. You can see a full app [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App) too.
For voice recognition, you can refer [here](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/).

This is how you create a service.
Better to put your media code in service. It is best way to play media in background.

```
public class serv extends Service{

    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public void onCreate()
    {   
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.b);
        mp.setLooping(false);
    }
    public void onDestroy()
    {       
        mp.stop();
    }
    public void onStart(Intent intent,int startid){

        Log.d(tag, "On start");
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

where raw is folder created in resources. and R.raw.b is an mp3 file.
Call this service just before you fire this intent.

```
/**
 * Fire an intent to start the voice recognition activity.
 */
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Handle the results from the voice recognition activity.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        // Populate the wordsList with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        wordsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                matches));
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```